# Android SDK missing emulator-arm on Linux

Tags: android, android-emulator

It seems like the latest versions of the Android emulator on Linux are missing the "emulator-arm" executable. I have version 29.3.4 and whenever I try to run an ARM AVD, I get the following error:

> PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU.

Everywhere I find this error, people talk about Avast putting "emulator-arm" on quarantine, but I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, so that's clearly not the case here. I've downloaded the emulator straight from the repository using the following link

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-6110076.zip

and the binaries for other architectures are really not there. What happened to them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's for those facing the same situation. Apparently I'm outdated and these binaries have been removed a while ago.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/12/emulator-2810-canary.html

They now have an image that can translate arm to x86.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/09/android-p-x86-system-images-google-play.html

I would like to emulate Android 5.1, but it seems that won't be possible with the latest SDK. You either downgrade or take that Android P image. =/